# How to reduce or smooth out the polygons in my render?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

First time I looked at this through the Blender UI it looked ok, but once I rendered it, I realized that there were polygons all over the place in the render.

The viewport in the blender UI was so much smaller that they weren't visible. 
How would I detect and smooth those out either before or during render?

[image]

Comment: This could be number of things, first did you set smooth shading on object, secondly did you use normal map for your material if yes make sure it is set up properly since it can sometimes cause things like this if not used properly. Also are you sure you have enough polygons here it seems to me that you used displace modifier, anyway you might want to slap subsurf modifier on object since it looks like lack of the geometry.

Comment: Sorry I literally downloaded and started working with Blender this morning, following youtube videos. Yes I used displace modifier. How would I use a subsurface scattering modifier? I put one on the displacement, and it flattened out the entire scene.

Comment: Not subsurface scattering that is shader. The subdivision surface modifier, add one before displacement modifier, but be aware of how many levels of it do you set because it can freeze the PC if overdone. Anyway you can try just with right click on the model and choose smooth shading and see if that'll do the trick if not try with modifier as I described above. If you want you can upload your .blend file and link it in the question so we can look into it.